# Mailto: Chrome issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mailto

Good afternoon,
I am using this function:

```
function sendMail() {
link="mailto:monemail@blabla.ca?body=MonText&subject=MySubject";
window.top.location.href = link;
}
```

In IE, the email message pops-up and the To, Subject & Body are filled.
In Chrome, the email message pops-up and only the To and the Body are filled.

I try reversed them, adding &amp, adding ";", same result, everything after the "&" is not taken in consideration..

Any idea why?

Thank you!

Comment: your body=Montext is preceded by a "?" - why not replace the & with a question mark, it is what separates the mail to and body statements?

Comment: I made a quick page to test this, and Chrome passed all three fields into Outlook. Remember, mailto links with parameters are not a standard, and both browsers and email clients (Including web based) must handle the parameters properly.

Comment: @SolarMike It's a query string, that's what it is supposed to be.

Comment: @SolarMike the `?` denotes the start of the parameter string. Each `&` denotes a new parameter.

Comment: Acording to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Email_links) this link is right

Comment: ok thanks guys- just thought it looked odd.

Comment: Thank you all! So the same Outlook opens when using Chrome and IE, which is Outlook 2010. IE is IE 11 and Chrome is Version 54.0.2840.99. What other info do you need?

Comment: Nobody has any idea?? :-(